# Performing column select over multiple dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply

I have looked around a lot for this answer, they get close but no cigar. I am trying to perform a selection of columns over multiple dataframes. I can do this and return a list, but I wish to preserve the dataframes in the global environment. I want to keep the dataframes separate for ease of use and visibility in Rstudio. For example I am selecting columns based on their name as so, for one dataframe:

```
E07 <- E07[,c("Block","Name","F635.Mean","F532.Mean","B635.Mean","B532")]
```

I have x amount of data frames listed in dflist so I have written this function:

```
columnselect<-function(df){df[,c("Block","Name","F635.Mean","F532.Mean","B635.Mean","B532")];df}
```

I then wish to apply this over the dflist as so:

```
lapply(X=dflist,FUN=columnselect)
```

This returns the function over the dflist however the data tables remain unchanged. How do I apply the function over multiple dataframes without returning them in a list.

Many thanks
M

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @EdChum R. OP even tagged it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns the data frames unchanged because this is the last thing evaluated in your function. Instead of:

```
columnselect<-function(df){
               df[,c("Block","Name","F635.Mean","F532.Mean","B635.Mean","B532")]
               df}
```

It should be:

```
columnselect<-function(df){
               df[,c("Block","Name","F635.Mean","F532.Mean","B635.Mean","B532")]
               }
```

Having the last `df` in your function simply returned the full df that you passed in the function.

As for the second question that you would like to have the data.frames in the global environment rather than in the list (which is bad practice just so you know; it is always better to keep those in the list) you need the `list2env` function i.e.:

```
mylist <- lapply(X=dflist,FUN=columnselect)

list2env(mylist, envir = globalenv())
```

Using this the data.frames in the global environment will be updated.